# Vue не может найти роут в laravel когда помещаю его в middleware

Tags: laravel, vue.js, маршрутизация, middleware, sanctum

Имею раздельные приложения
1.Vue
2.Laravel
В случае авторизации Vue в Laravel использую laravel sanctum и пытаясь защитить маршруты доступные только аутентифицированным пользователям решил помесить /logout в middleware и как результат Vue перестал находить этот маршрут возвращая статус 500. Если я убираю этот маршрут из middleware, то вью снова видит его[image: middleware]

Есть также маршрут /user и он отлично работает находясь в этом middleware и также прекрасно чувствует себя за его пределами
Подскажите пожалуйста, чем может быть вызвано такое поведение?

Comment: php artisan route:clear - кэш роутов очищали?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , нет не чистил, но сейчас опять поместил логаут в middleware, отчистил и попробовал - не помогло(
Но спасибо за попытку
Если есть ещё идеи, то с удовольствием попробую)

Answer (score 0):

В общем в моём случае я:

1. зашёл в конфиг sanctum.php и добавил туда защитника "guard" => "web"
2. Зашёл в мой UserController в котором делаю logout и прописал

```
Auth::guard('web')->logout();
```

До этого было

```
Auth::logout()
```

и я получал ошибку что метод RequestGuard::logout не найден
**Примечание:** обращаю внимание на то, что logout у меня подчёркнут красным будто это ошибка, не обращайте на это внимание, он будет работать.
[image: Auth::guard('web')->logout()]

Comment: Так же обращу внимание на то, что нет необходимости делать собственного защитника "api" если вы создаёте роуты в api.php. В доке Sanctum ясно сказано,что он работает именно с защитником "web"
*Я могу ошибаться, но прочитав это и потестировав для себя сделал этот вывод

Comment: Добавлю ещё такой момент, что были люди которые говорили о том, что нужно написать php artisan route:clear и php artisan optimize. Могу отметить, что в моём случае оно мне никак не навредило, но и не помогло, но возможно поможет вам